# Mysql query for blank data

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I run a query that would perform the following?

Table: users
Columns: username, email

If username is blank/empty, update username with email in that row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming by `BLANK/EMPTY` means `NULL` or nothing,

if you mean you only want to project or `SELECT`, use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(username, email) username,
       email
FROM   users
```

but if you want to permanently update the field,

```
UPDATE users
SET    username =  email
WHERE  userName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update users set username = email where username is null  or username = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE users
SET username = email
WHERE username = ""
OR username is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    users
SET
    users.username = users.email
WHERE users.username IS NULL OR LENGTH(users.username)=0;
```